# Is it a bad practise to use the return statement in any loop blocks?

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [It's considered a bad pratice use return to end a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959250/its-considered-a-bad-pratice-use-return-to-end-a-function)

Hi,
  In any programming language is it a bad practise to use the return statement in any loop blocks? if so why?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by loop backs?

Comment: I've already answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959250/its-considered-a-bad-pratice-use-return-to-end-a-function/5959279#5959279. The answer is always no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say it is bad. Some people don't like it - the reason being that you cannot read just a part of a method, because it might happen you never come to that part, because of return in loop before that part. If you can avoid it and return only at the end of the method, you can look at different parts of the method. One way to do that is to use result variable and carry it through the method, other way, better in functional programming, is to use recursion instead of loops.

Comment: Screbak - Thanks. I generally use result variable method if it comes to return in loops. But in most of the other programmers code I see return statements inside a loop. Anyways your answers is satisifying :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can not think of any reason why you shouldn't.  However, I am sure they exist. Like most things with developing applications, it depends on the assumptions/decisions that you make.